# Numbers in cts:word query in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a cts:word-query which is having number as the text value.
`cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:word-query("226"))`

This query will fetch results matching to only 226 in the documents. But I need to get the documents which contain 0026 also.

Example:
This is abc.xml

```
<a>
<b>00226</b>
</a>
```

This is abc1.xml

```
<a>
<b>226</b>
</a>
```

If I give the query as `cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:word-query("226"))`, it will fetch only abc1.xml and if the query is `cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:word-query("00226"))`, it will fetch only abc.xml.

But I need to get both the documents, irrespective of leading zeros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use a wild card character (*****) and add the `wildcarded` option

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:word-query("*226", ('wildcarded')))
```

**EDIT:**

Although this matches the example documents, as Kishan points out in the comments, **the wildcard also matches unwanted documents** (e.g. containing "226226").

Since range indexes are not an option in this case because the data is mixed, here is an alternative hack:

```
cts:search(
    fn:doc(),
    cts:word-query(
        for $lead in ('', '0', '00', '000') 
        return $lead || "226"))
```

Obviously, this depends on how many leading zeros there can be and will only work if this is known and limited.

Comment: if i use a *226 in query, it will match any number ending with 226. Suppose i have 5225226. It will match and return this document also. So I cant use a wildcards.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an element range index on the element `<b>` in the database with scalar type `int` or `long`, then you do the following query, it should return both documents:

```
let $query := cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("b"),"=",00226)
return cts:search(fn:doc(),$query)
```

Comment: I am not able to define a element range index of type long because the element <b> may containg text also with the numbers.